# Unreliable (UDP) Transport Hints in Rospy and Rosjava

Tags: rospy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't been able to find anything to indicate if subscribers for rospy or rosjava can currently use UDP transport.

It looks like rospy [uses UDPROS at some point](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospy/html/rospy.impl.udpros.UDPROSHandler-class.html), but I haven't seen examples or documentation on its use.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28322/unreliable-(udp)-transport-hints-in-rospy-and-rosjava/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, they cannot.  The code in rospy is an incomplete/unfinished implementation.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2